# How to select substring of each array in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have the following array.

```
@arr = ["Ac,Ab,Aa", "Ba,Bb,Bd", "Ca,Cc,Cb", "Dd,Da,Dc", "aA,aC,aD", "bD,bA,bB", "cB,cA,cC", "dD,dC,dA"]
```

Now I want to extract the first two letters of each item.

```
@firsttwo = ["Ac", "Ba", "Ca", "Dd", "aA", "bD", "cB", "dD"]
```

How can I achieve this in Ruby.

I tried this but it didn't work.

```
    @firsttwo = @combi.select{ |item| item[0, 1]}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [`Array#map`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-map) :

```
@arr = ["Ac,Ab,Aa", "Ba,Bb,Bd", "Ca,Cc,Cb", "Dd,Da,Dc", "aA,aC,aD", "bD,bA,bB", "cB,cA,cC", "dD,dC,dA"]
@arr.map { |item| item[0..1] }
# => ["Ac", "Ba", "Ca", "Dd", "aA", "bD", "cB", "dD"]
```

`#select` selects the element from receiver, if *block* returns `true`. Now in your case `item[0..1]` giving a *string* object in each iteration, which has *truthy* value, thus `#select` selects all element from the receiver.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@firsttwo = @arr.map { |item| item.split(",")[0] }
```

You are currently using `select`. This returns a collection where each iteration returns true. You seem to want to preform the same operation on each member of the collection without doing any testing. `.map` is suited for this.